# Prevent redirection of cf7 to thankyou on error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a cf7 with 3 fields: name, email and select box and in the dropdown, based on choices form redirects to different thank you pages. The problem is if a form shows some error message like there was an error in sending the message, invalid input etc. the form should not redirect to a thank you page.

I tried Contact Form 7 Custom DOM Events like wpcf7mailfailed, wpcf7invalid.

```
function cf7_footer_script(){ ?>

<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    if ( '7084' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {

      var lpLocation =  document.getElementById("careers").value;

      if (lpLocation == "Hire better employees") {
        location = 'url1';
      } else if (lpLocation == "I want to match people to the best careers") {
        location = 'url2';
      }
      else if(lpLocation=="I want to learn more about both"){
        location = 'url3';
      }

    }
}, false ); 
</script>

<?php } 

add_action('wp_footer', 'cf7_footer_script');
```

I want to prevent redirection on error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change Contact Form 7 Custom DOM Event, Use wpcf7mailsent instead of wpcf7submit.

***wpcf7mailsent — Fires when an Ajax form submission has completed successfully, and mail has been sent.***

```
function cf7_footer_script() { ?>

    <script>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
        if ( '7084' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
            var lpLocation =  document.getElementById( "careers" ).value;
                if ( lpLocation == "Hire better employees" ) {
                    location = 'url1';
                } else if ( lpLocation == "I want to match people to the best careers" ) {
                    location = 'url2';
                } else if( lpLocation == "I want to learn more about both" ) {
                    location = 'url3';
                }
            }
        }, false ); 
    </script>

<?php } 

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cf7_footer_script' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try with this "document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) "
function cf7_footer_script(){ ?>

<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( '7084' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {

      var lpLocation =  document.getElementById("careers").value;

      if (lpLocation == "Hire better employees") {
        location = 'url1';
      } else if (lpLocation == "I want to match people to the best careers") {
        location = 'url2';
      }
      else if(lpLocation=="I want to learn more about both"){
        location = 'url3';
      }

    }
}, false ); 
</script>

<?php } 

add_action('wp_footer', 'cf7_footer_script');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **wpcf7mailsent** instead of **wpcf7submit** event.